# how to drop rows based on some condition about the content in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to drop some of the rows from a dataframe (read from .txt file).
In other words I would like to keep only the rows which are interesting.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
      data
0     ID-0123456789              #ID I need
1     AG-TH/RGS_Srbcd_675F9_TRL  #randrom text I dont need
2     15.00                      #value I need (belongs to ID above)
3     NDFSD/+vbdgfnhj_46/THS     #randrom text I dont need
4     Sgbfd_FG-fdg_GRT/DR.x      #randrom text I dont need
5     ID-1234567890              #ID I need
6     3_F/H_ & S/J               #randrom text I dont need
7     0.00                       #value I need (belongs to ID above)
...   ...                        ...
```

There is no pattern, sometimes there are more "random text I dont need" rows, sometimes not.
I tried dropping rows based on content, like keeping `df["data"].str.startswith("ID")` which keeps the ID... rows but I lost the values.
I tried combining this with `type()`, but the values in the column are also strings.
My next idea was to focus on digits, but the "random text I dont need" rows also contain digits in some cases.
I would like to get a df like this after dropping the unnecessary rows:

```
      data
0     ID-0123456789              #ID I need
2     15.00                      #value I need (belongs to ID above)
5     ID-1234567890              #ID I need
7     0.00                       #value I need (belongs to ID above)
...   ...                        ...
```

Any idea?
It is not a problem if the IDs and values will be in a different column, in fact my goal is to get in the end:

```
     ID                 value
0    ID-0123456789      15.00
1    ID-1234567890      0.00
...
```

Thank you in advance!
Sorry if it is obvious, I'm new to python and programming.

Comment: It looks like you have to do some preprocessing before using `pandas` at all. How does your data look like? You said it's a text file. What does that mean? Is it a file with lots and lots of contiguous text? Or is it an already-built dataframe, with rows distributed with no pattern at all?

Comment: Hi,
The text file contains many rows: an ID row, some rows with the random text, some rows with always the same text (e.g.: "pink elephant") and a row with a value. This repeates, the problem is that the number and the content of rows with random text is changeing. After reading the file I already get rid of the "pink elephant" like rows.

Comment: It would help to make your sample data more representative of the problem, and show expected output based on that input, to make a [mcve] so that we can provide a more accurate answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a "dirty" solution which might work (depending on what's actually in the frame):

```
data = [
    'ID-0123456789',
    'AG-TH/RGS_Srbcd_675F9_TRL',
    15.00,
    'NDFSD/+vbdgfnhj_46/THS',
    'Sgbfd_FG-fdg_GRT/DR.x',
    'ID-1234567890',
    '3_F/H_ & S/J',
    0.00,
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['data'])

df = pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame(df[df['data'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:3]) == 'ID-'].values, columns=['ID']),
     pd.DataFrame(df[df['data'].apply(type) == float].values, columns=['value'])],
     axis=1)
```

Or (looks a bit more civil):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(df[df['data'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:3]) == 'ID-']['data'],
                      df[df['data'].apply(type) == float]['data']),
                  columns=['ID', 'value'])
```

Output:

```
              ID value
0  ID-0123456789    15
1  ID-1234567890     0
```

If there's a chance that some of the random text starts with `ID-` then something like this would be safer:

```
import re

re_id = re.compile(r'^ID-\d{10}$')
def is_id(obj):
    return bool(re_id.match(str(obj).strip()))

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(df[df['data'].apply(is_id)]['data'],
                      df[df['data'].apply(type) == float]['data']),
                  columns=['ID', 'value'])
```

**Some comments**:

The [**apply**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method of a DataFrame/Series "applies" here

```
df['data'].apply(is_id)
```

the function `is_id` to each row, i.e. single elements, since `df['data']` is a Series. The result is a Series of `bool` values, `True` where an ID is found, `False` otherwise:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
```

If you "plug" this Series into the original frame `df[...]` every row with a corresponding `False` gets dropped.

The built-in [**zip**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#zip) function "pairs" iterables into an iterator. To illustrate what it does:

```
list(zip([1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
```

leads to

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]
```

You can use it with an aritrary number of iterables.

Comment: Hi, I tried the last code using my file and it worked perfectly, thank you!
I get that you are using a regular expressio to sort out the rows containing an ID, but I have some difficulty understanding the combination of zip and apply. Would you be so kind and add some comments? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @user14421092 Nice! I wasn't a 100% sure if it would work beyond the sample data. One single irregularity would break the result. I've just added some comments. I hope they are helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Is the random text always the same? If so, you could try:

```
#converting to a series, finding the ones that match, and adding back to the table
find_text = df['data']
#create series that has 0 for what matches the ads
text_found = find_Ads.str.find("random text I don't need")
#add column to table with 0's
df['Random'] = text_found
#create new table with those rows with zero gone
df = df[df['Random'] != 1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

This would create a series that finds every row with your random text and assigns it a 1. you'd then be able to add the series as a new column to your original frame, and then filter for just the rows that did not find that string.

Comment: Hi,
The random text rows contain various text. I already get rid of the rows with always the same content, using some similar solution like your proposal. (I added a flag column instead of using a new series, but the method is more or less the same.)